# Is there any way to have a discord bot track every message sent in a channel and store that information somewhere else?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots, message

I've been wanting to code something like this for a while, some code that triggers whenever a message is sent in a specific channel, when this is triggered, the bot gets the text that was in the message and stores it somewhere else, in a database of some sort, does anyone know any code that could work for my issue?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you tried looking at tutorials or the documentation? What issues are you running into?

Answer (score 0):

Probaly something like this. Its **very simple**.

First, we create a **local list** and adds the **message content** to it, if someone sends a **message**. We're using the `on_message` event to **check for new messages**.

But this list **resets everytime the bot re-starts**. If you want that list **doesn't reset itself**, you should **save the data into an database**, like MySQL or SQLite.

```
# Create the list
msg_list = []

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    
    # Check if message has content
    
    if message.content is not None:
    
        # Add message content to list

        msg_list.append(message.content)

        # print the list to the console

        print(msg_list)
```

---

### Save messages from the past

If you want to save all messages from the past into this list, you need that. But **you should keep in mind that this process could take a long time**!!

```
@bot.command()
async def past_count(ctx, channel=None):

    # Check if channel argument is empty

    if channel is None:

        # if yes, use channel from the command

        channel = ctx.channel
    
    async for message in channel.history(limit=None):

        # Check if message has content
    
        if message.content is not None:
    
            # Add message content to list
    
            msg_list.append(message.content)
            
    await ctx.reply("Look in the console for the message list!")
    
    for message in msg_list:
        print(message)
```

---

### Sources

- [on_message Event](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=#discord.on_message)
- [Create Commands](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html)
- [TextChannels](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=#textchannel)

Comment: thank you so much, I wanted to make this program for servers that have people with tourette syndrome actually, sometimes a "tic" (aka what happens when tourettes happens) can happen in the form of typing, so I wanted to make this to have a log of people's typing tics

Comment: Also @Razzer how would I have it go to a database automatically?

Comment: That would be an another question.